# Haskell multiple functors

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I'm making a fibonacci heap implementation in Haskell, and I'm not sure exactly what the clean way to do it.

For example, I want to order the nodes. So I can do something like:

```
instance Ord (FibNode e) where
  f1 `compare` f2 = (key f1) `compare` (key f2)
```

This would be more easily done if I made `FibNode` a monad. But other times I want to fold across the node's siblings, or fold across their children etc. So defining a functor where `f x = f $ key x` won't work all the time.

Apart from defining my own `fmapKey`, `fmapSibs`, `fmapKids`... is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a type constructor an instance of Functor in more than one way.
But you can make various newtype wrappers around your type that each has its own Functor instance.  But that's not really any more convenient than defining your own fmap functions.

Comment: I figured as much. It's just that when I think I've found a limit of Haskell I've usually just found a limit to my thinking. So I wanted to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1):

The (Fibonacci) heap is an inherently impure, destructively-updated data structure with [specific asymptotic runtime guarantees for various operations on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times). I would be surprised if you can maintain these guarantees with a straightforward translation to a pure version. My suggestion would be to to make it an *impure* data structure using something like the ST or IO arrays. This would make for a much more direct implementation of the classic algorithms.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to define a "specific asymptotic runtime guarantees" for someone who knows what the individual words mean?

Comment: @harpo: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for a definition of asymptotic running time bounds. The "specific guarantees" I'm referring to are outlined in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times)